# I am getting same value of every button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

i have fetch the data from database every thing work fine but problem is when i submit ajax request to test.php i got same value of every button 
I am very week in Ajax and Java so please help me ,i am confuse how to get value of every button separately and submit to test.php file

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    $letter = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM letters order by id DESC");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($letter) > 0) {
        while ($rows_letter=mysqli_fetch_array($letter)) {
            $id = $rows_letter['id'];
            $subject = $rows_letter['subject'];
            $status = $rows_letter['status'];
            ?>

            <tr>
                <th class="text-center" scope="row">1</th>
                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $subject ;?></td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <?php 
                    if ($status == 1) {
                        echo '<mark style="background-color: #5cb85c; color:white;"> Successfully Sent </mark>'; 
                    } else { 
                        echo '<mark  style="background-color:#f0ad4e; color:white;"> Not  Sent Yet </mark>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                    <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span> Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block"> 
                    <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span>  Move To Trash</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onclick="startsend();" id="id"  value="<?php echo $id;?>"class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
                    <span class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></span> Send To All</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }       
    ?>
</tbody>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    //AJAX function
    function startsend() {
        var id = $('#id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data:{ id: id
            },
            success: function(msg){
                alert( "Button Id is " + msg );
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and this is my test.php file

```php
<?php 
$id = $_POST['id']; echo $id; 
//// rest of process according to id 
?>
```

Comment: Did you forget adding your test.php code ?

Comment: print $id to be sure they are different numbers than put them in array like id="id[]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, pass the id as `param` to `ajax`

Html:

```
<td><button type="button" onclick="startsend(<?php echo $id;?>);"
      id="id"  value="<?php echo $id;?>"class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
      <span class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></span> Send To All</button></td>
```

Ajax:

```
function startsend(id) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data:{ id: id },
        success: function(msg){
          alert( "Button Id is " + msg );
        }
      });
    }
```